# What additives could make a masonry unit water-repellent but vapor-permeable?

Tags: water

I'm curious about some of the wondrous materials available today are able to repel liquid water but permit water vapor to pass through. I've heard that housewrap-type plastics accomplish this by being perforated with microscopic holes that are slightly too large for liquid water, but large enough for the vaporous form to pass through. I have no idea how [silicate mineral paints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicate_mineral_paint) do it, though.

Housewraps and paints are thin films, though. I'd like to learn about how such properties could be imparted to a masonry unit like a compressed earth block. Could you cast such a block with a mixture of soil and some additive that would grant this kind of water repellency but allow water vapor to pass though?

Comment: Is liquid water molecule any larger than a steam molecule? Isn't there rather some trick with hydrogenium bonds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be waterglass. That's the carrier for silicate mineral paints.

Comment: I appreciate it that you took the time to write an answer yourself, but could you please elaborate so that the next person who had this problem would find a solution here?